# Java: Unable to unzip a gzip compressed file?

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I am trying to unzip a gzip file content that I have read into memory as a String.

```
    /**
     * Read file content into a String
     */
    private static String readUsingFileInputStream(String fileName) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);


            while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {
                sb.append(new String(buffer));
                buffer = new byte[10];
            }
            fis.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //...
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Unzip file content
     */
    public static String unzip(final byte[] compressed) {
        try (final GZIPInputStream gzipInput = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
            final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
            IOUtils.copy(gzipInput, stringWriter, UTF_8);
            return stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException("Error while decompression!", e);
        }
    }
```

Then in my `main` method, I am doing:

```
String compressedData = readUsingFileInputStream("/path/to/my/compressed_file_json.gz");
System.out.println(unzip(compressedData.getBytes(UTF_8)));
```

But I am getting following error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:166)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:92)
```

What am I doing wrong? I have verified that file is in fact GZIP format and it's not corrupted.

Note: I am aware that I can input the FileInputStream directly in the GZIPInputStream, but for the purposes of the actual problem, I don't have access to FileInputStream, just resulting the String.

Comment: You're treating your bytes as string and then convert it to UTF-8. Don't do that.

Comment: Is there way to unzip if I have only the string?

Comment: You need to receive the gzip as byte[]. A gzip byte stream isn't convertable to String reliably - whatever encoding you try, the conversion as String and back is unlikely to return the original bytes.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... What am I doing wrong? I have verified that file is in fact GZIP format and it's not corrupted. ..."*

Return a *byte array* from *readUsingFileInputStream*, and use the [*String* constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.nio.charset.Charset)) to create a *UTF-8* value.

```java
/**
 * Read file content into a String
 */
private static byte[] readUsingFileInputStream(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
        return fis.readAllBytes();
    }
}

/**
 * Unzip file content
 */
public static String unzip(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    try (final GZIPInputStream gzipInput = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed))) {
        return new String(gzipInput.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Example

```java
byte[] compressedData = readUsingFileInputStream("/path/to/my/compressed_file_json.gz");
System.out.println(unzip(compressedData));
```